# MBProgressHUD Crash in KVO Register

Tags: ios, crash, key-value-observing, mbprogresshud

i am writing one app and use XX.framework. Both app and framework include MBProgressHUD. In my app, i will use MBProgressHUD firstly, it works well.
But after that while XX.framework use MBProgressHUD, it will crash in MBProgressHUD KVO register.If i rename MBProgressHUD in XX.framework, everything works fine. Anyone can help to explain the reason for me?

Comment: same with this case:I can reproduce this by including MBProgressHUD as a static library in a dynamic framework as well as the main project. Both are swift with MBProgressHUD included in the bridging header.

The app launches and calls MBProgressHUD from code in the main app binary, which displays as expected. At a later stage the app calls code which runs in the dynamic framework, which causes a runtime exception.

The solution is to remove the link to MBProgressHUD from the main project.

Sorry I don't have time to come up with a sample project.